# Django, Celery, Pytest и база данных

Tags: python, django, celery, pytest

Есть например такой таск:

```
@shared_task
def do_something():
    from django_app.models import TestModel
    TestModel(foo='foo').save()
```

И есть например такой тест (для работы с БД в тестах используется pytest-django):

```
@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)
@pytest.mark.celery(task_always_eager=False)
def test_celery_task(celery_worker):
    from django_app.tasks import do_something
    async_result = do_something.delay()
    async_result.get()
```

В Python 3.6 работает. А в Python 2.7 и PyPy не работает — пишет, что `no such table: djangoapp_testmodel`.

Почему? И как мне тогда вообще тестировать Celery с базой данных, если использование `task_always_eager=True` [запрещено документацией](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/testing.html)?

При этом `live_server` вроде работает с базой нормально, если что ([не без проблем](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/issues/454), но всё же)